# Canvas drawImage draws only some part of SVG

Tags: canvas, svg, drawimage, cgcontextdrawimage

I have chart SVG of width around 500 and height around 300.
I have scaled it using scale attribute in SVG.
Now when I tried drawing it on canvas it draws on some part from top left corner of the SVG.
If I open SVG file separately in browser it shows the whole image also the image tag which I have created for canvas also shows whole image.

I have also tried using different source and destination offsets, width and height but it didn't work.

I am clueless now what could be the problem.

Following is ths sample code where I have changed the SVG.

**NOTE**:- this also crops image but shows full SVG when I provide source and destination offsets, width and height. Unfortunatly it doesn't help me with my SVG.

```
var data = 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"><rect width="1000" height="350" fill="rgb(0, 255, 0)" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" /></svg>';

var canvas = $("<canvas width='1024' height='360' style=\"border: 1px solid red;\">");
$(canvas).appendTo('body').css('position', 'absolute').css('top', 0);
var image = new Image;
$(image).appendTo("body")
    .width(defaultZoomWidth).height(360)
    .css("position", "fixed").css("top", "400px");
image.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var context = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    }, 1000);
};
image.src = data;
```

Comment: Hello I have added sample code. I have changed the SVG here. 
**NOTE** :- This also crops image but shows full SVG when I provide source and destination offsets, width and height. Unfortunatly it doesn't help me with my SVG.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that you **must** set absolute `width` and `height` attributes on the `<svg>` node, not percentages, which will be the default if nothing is set (`100%`).

As side notes, the most supported dataURI header syntax is
`data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8,` + your_svg_markup.

Also, it's always better to `encodeURIComponent` your serialized svg markup when setting it as a dataURI.

So here it is :

```js
var svgString = '<svg width="1000" height="1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"><rect width="1000" height="350" fill="rgb(0, 255, 0)" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" /></svg>';

var data = 'data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, '+ encodeURIComponent(svgString);

var canvas = $("<canvas width='1024' height='360' style=\"border: 1px solid red;\">");
$(canvas).appendTo('body').css('position', 'absolute').css('top', 0);
var image = new Image;
image.onload = function() {
    var context = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
};
image.src = data;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Kaildo.
Your solution really worked. 
What was going wrong is I was not giving width and height as attributes to SVG instead setting them in style.
Thanks a lot.